# How to handle multiple device clients provisioned through DPS(Group Symmetric key) to IoT Central from a gateway device

Tags: azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-central, azure-iot-dps

We have a gateway device(not running IoT edge runtime). We want to connect multiple BLE or Zigbee sensors to the gateway and provision/register them through our gateway device to IoT Central as different devices using group symmetric key approach.

We have seen multiple sample codes for the provisioning and registering the devices using group symmetric key to generate device-specific SAS key. But these don't have an approach for handling multiple device clients after registering and connecting to IoT Central

[python sdk provisioning with group symmetric key](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/sync-samples/provision_symmetric_key_group.py)

[iot_central_python_sample](https://github.com/iot-for-all/Iot_Central_Python_Sample#iot_central_python_sample)

After connecting the device we need to use device client of the SDK to send telemetry and receive commands to/from IoT Central.

Consider if we want to use the same code for multiple sensors, we need to have multiple device clients(threads) running.

**Please suggest a better approach** to handle multiple devices for sending telemetry and receiving commands to/from IoT Central

Comment: The azure-iot-device python SDK has a known problem with multiple client instances as noted https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/wiki/pitfalls#its-easy-to-create-multiple-client-instances-and-cause-instabilit . 

I think this implies that you cannot use python for your edge module if you want to do identity translation (which is what It think you are trying to do), only protocol translation.

Answer (score 0):

This might help with your use case: https://github.com/Larouex/IoTCNanoBLE33